# possible to hide browser and control it programmatically ? .net or vb6

Tags: .net, vb6

basically using autoit, what happens is that IE windows pops up, and autoit clicks on stuff, and can control it and so on.

what i'd like is a way to hide the browser and still let autoit do it's magic. the browser should not be visible in taskbar or system tray but should be visible as a browser.exe in process window.

autoit solution works for me, but its very annoying that only IE is controllable, and IE must popup each time autoit code runs.

Comment: What do you want the browser to do for you and why? Whatever it is, there are probably better ways of doing it than sending clicks to a hidden browser window.

Comment: hmm... Sounds like malware/pay-per-click exploit....

What's the end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of functions for IE that will let you do things even with hidden browser:

`_IECreate`, `_IELinkClickByIndex` so on so forth. The first one has option to start window hidden and then you just play it. Just takes a bit of time to master this :) Check all commands starting with `_IE` and you should find what you're looking for. It's a bit more complicated then sending simple mouse clicks in right areas but it's a bit more fool proof if you write it correctly (checking for errors etc).

Answer (score 0):

Perl, Ruby and Python all have a module available called "Mechanize", designed to automate interaction with websites. This is a Ruby example: [http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html.)